# Why am i getting time limit exceeded?

Tags: java

I am getting time limit exceeded?

Similar Char
Problem Description
Tahir and Mamta are woking in a project in TCS. Tahir being a problem solver came up with an interesting problem for his friend Mamta.

Problem consists of a string of length N and contains only small case alphabets.

It will be followed by Q queries, in which each query will contain an integer P (1<=P<=N) denoting a position within the string.

Mamta's task is to find the alphabet present at that location and determine the number of occurrence of same alphabet preceding the given location P.

Mamta is busy with her office work. Therefore, she asked you to help her.

Constraints
1 <= N <= 500000

S consisting of small case alphabets

1 <= Q <= 10000

1 <= P <= N

Input Format
First line contains an integer N, denoting the length of string.

Second line contains string S itself consists of small case alphabets only ('a' - 'z').

Third line contains an integer Q denoting number of queries that will be asked.

Next Q lines contains an integer P (1 <= P <= N) for which you need to find the number occurrence of character present at the Pth location preceeding P.

Output
For each query, print an integer denoting the answer on single line.

Test Case

Explanation
Example 1

Input

9

abacsddaa

2

9

3

Output

3

1

Explanation

Here Q = 2

For P=9, character at 9th location is 'a'. Number of occurrences of 'a' before P i.e., 9 is three.

Similarly for P=3, 3rd character is 'a'. Number of occurrences of 'a' before P. i.e., 3 is one.

```
import java.io.*;

public class simchar
{
    public static void main(String gg[]) throws Exception
    {
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int n=Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        String s=reader.readLine();
        if(s.length()!=n) return;
        int q=Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        int qq;
        int []count=new int[q];
        char someChar;
        for(int j=0;j<q;j++)
        {
            qq=Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
            someChar=s.charAt(qq-1);
            for(int k=0;k<s.substring(0,qq-1).length();k++){
                if((s.substring(0,(qq-1)).charAt(k)==someChar)) count[j]++;
            }
            System.out.println(count[j]);
        }

        reader.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume this some kind of hackerrank question (or similiar). If thats the case just link the proper problem description in your question. If you get time limit exceed it means your soultion is not performant enough, i.e. the complexity is to high.

Comment: Try refactoring the various `s.substring(0,(qq-1))` calls into a single call (within the `for(int j ...)` loop body). Right now, you call `substring` qq times per loop. That's `q` * `qq` calls to an O(n) method, which can definitely add up. As an aside, please consider more helpful variable names, especially when asking for help. It's that much harder to follow the code when all the variables are `q`, `j`, etc.

Comment: Original question: https://brainly.in/question/11174859

Comment: @yshavit The `substring` calls are needless. `substring(0,qq-1).length()` is the same as just `qq - 1`, and `s.substring(0,(qq-1)).charAt(k)` is the same as `s.charAt(k)`.

Comment: @OleV.V. still getting TLE

Comment: Yes, @mohitkaothekar, I expected that. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Ole's answer, you also need to consider some "micro" optimizations:

I suspect that most of the time will be spent executing this loop:

```
for(int k=0;k<s.substring(0,qq-1).length();k++){
  if((s.substring(0,(qq-1)).charAt(k)==someChar)) count[j]++;
}
```

Lets look at a couple of aspects:

- `k<s.substring(0,qq-1).length()` creates a substring just so that it can work out its length.  But we know what that length will be:  `qq`!  So you have created a new string and copied `qq` characters for no good reason.  Inefficient.  Pointless.
- `s.substring(0,(qq-1)).charAt(k)==someChar` creates another string and then gets its `k`th character.  But the `k`th character of the substring is also the `k`th character of the original string `s`.  (Think about it!)  So, once again the substring creating is pointless.
- Both of those unnecessary calculations are repeated `qq` times.   It is the same (unnecessary) computation done `2 x qq` times.

Note: this analysis takes no account of whether your code is correct or the algorithm is optimal.  It is purely about micro-efficiency.   What you have done is turn an `O(N^2)` algorithm into an `O(N^3)` algorithm ... due to the unnecessary substring creation.

Comment: Thank you for the supplement. When I noted that the `substring` calls were needless, I had not realized that they were this expensive. They are the difference between *O(s * q)* and *O(s^2 * q)*. Ans *s* can be much larger than *q*. On modern Java versions that is. I've read that `substring` was *O(1)* on early Jave versions, but today copies the chars, so is *O(n)*.

Comment: They got of rid of String => substring sharing of the backing array because it could lead to insidious memory leak problems.

Answer (score 1):

For an efficient solution for a long string (up to 500000 letters) and many queries (up to 10000) you need to preprocess your string data somehow so that after that you can process each query fast. I suggest that for each of the 26 possible lowercase letters (the question explicitly says 'a' - 'z') find the position of the 1st, 2nd, 3rd occurrence, etc., and fill them into an array or list. Then for each query do binary search in the array for the position you got as input. Then the array index found will tell you the answer. This will reduce your time complexity from *O(s^2* * *q)* to *O(s + q* * *log(s))*.

If you don’t know binary search, look it up. Or use a `Map<Integer, Integer>` instead of the array or list.

Still more efficient, build an array the same length as the string and in each index store the answer to the query about that index. I believe that this can be implemented with complexity *O(s + q)*.

Link: [Original question on brainly.in](https://brainly.in/question/11174859)